# Create unique link for each existing employee in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

So we have a website where Employers can log in and add new employees they just hired. When you hit 'Submit' on the form asking for the employees info, a unique link is created that if they click on, it will take them to a page to view the handbook (Onboarding) and electronically sign for it. We recently have a new Employer who wanted to see if we could add his current 300 employees into the site and have each one view and sign the handbook. I able to dumb all 300 employees into the database with MySQL but the issue now is that a Unique Link was never created for all of them because the 'Submit' button was never pushed for each one. 
What do you guys think would be the best method to tackle this? Im not really sure how the Unique Links are created but I think I found the code that creates it. I was thinking of just creating a button that would create the link but I would have to tell it to do it for each of the 300 employees. I just cant seem to think of a better way.

```
<?php
ob_start();

//-------------------PAGE SETUP------------------------------------------------------
// Connect to the database
include( "db/connect.php" );
include( "db/dbFunctions.php" );
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Restrict Users who do not have the Onboarding service
if (!hasService($USERID,'Onboarding')) {header( 'Location: home.php' ,true,301) ;}

//Check to see if the user has access to this functionality
checkAccessToFunctionality($USERID,$USERTYPE,'ADDEMPLOYEE',true);

$client = getClient($_POST['clientid'],$USERID);
$clientID = $client->id;
$locationID = $_POST['locationid'];
$templateID = $_POST['templateid'];

//Update the data fields
if ($clientID)
{


    //Create the account and add data 
    $newuserID = createOnboardingEmployee();


    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','locationid',$_POST['locationid']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','firstname',$_POST['firstname']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','lastname',$_POST['lastname']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','middleinitial',$_POST['middleinitial']);

    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','ssn',$_POST['ssn']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','phone',$_POST['phone']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','hiredate',$_POST['dateofhire_year'].'-'.$_POST['dateofhire_month'].'-'.$_POST['dateofhire_day']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','startdate',$_POST['startdate_year'].'-'.$_POST['startdate_month'].'-'.$_POST['startdate_day']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','hourlyrate',$_POST['hourlyrate']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','addedby',$USERID);

    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','customfield1',$_POST['customfield1']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','customfield2',$_POST['customfield2']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','customfield3',$_POST['customfield3']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','customfield4',$_POST['customfield4']);
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','customfield5',$_POST['customfield5']);

    if (isset($_POST['noemail']))
        {
        setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','noemail','1');
        }   
    else{
        setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','emailaddress',$_POST['email']);    
    }



    //Set the employee's onboarding link
    setData($newuserID,'tblonboardingemployees','onboardinglink',$newuserID . '-' . GUID());

    //Set the onboarding template to use for the employee
    assignOnboardingTemplateToEmployee($templateID,$locationID,$newuserID,$USERID);


    //Send the onboarding link to the user
    sendOnboardingIntroEmail($USERID,$newuserID,$templateID);


    //auditaction($USERID,'USER',$newuserID,'User Added','UserType='.$_POST['usertype'],null);

    //Assign permission to all client data and locations
    //$permission = createUserPermission($newuserID,4,1,$clientID);

    //Assign the master user ID to the client record
    //setData($clientID,'tblclients','masteruserid',$newuserID);


}
else

{
    echo 'A location ID was not found. Had to stop. Sorry about that!.';
    ob_flush();
    exit(0);
}
header( 'Location: onboarding_addemployee_complete.php?id='. $newuserID  ) ;

ob_flush();
```

Comment: don't dumb your employees. It's bad for business and probably illegal

Comment: The unique link itself is probably stored in the DB somewhere to be checked again when the user clicks on the link (and make sure they didn't just create a link themselves).

Comment: Thanks @circusdei. Found it in the DB and was able to create my own.